# Static CLI instance throws AccessViolationException after subsequent tests when test execution engine is kept running

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio, unit-testing

So I have C++/CLI code for a complex calculator that computes hard stuff, exactly what doesn't matter for this question. In my application, I create an object that can be instantiated with different properties (`SignificantDigits` and `PruningLimit`) from different threads, each calling `Calculate` on the shared `CLICalculator`. I also don't want to initialize the CLI calculator every time I make a new instance of `MyCalculator` because it loads a resource which can be slow... besides, the resource is read-only and is never changed. The `Calculate` method in `CLICalculator` is also thread-safe.

```
public sealed class MyCalculator
{
    private static object _threadLock = new object();
    private static CLICalculator _calculator = null;

    private int _significantDigits= 6;
    private int _pruningLimit = 1E-8;

    private MyCalculator()
    {
        if (_calculator == null)
        {
            lock(_threadLock)
            {
                if (_calculator == null)
                {
                     _calculator = new CLICalculator("path/to/resource");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int SignificantDigits
    {
        get { return _significantDigits; }
        set { _significantDigits = value; }
    }

    public double PruningLimit
    {
        get { return _pruningLimit; }
        set { _pruningLimit = value; }
    }

    public double[,] PerformCalculation(string a, int b)
    {
        return _calculator.Calculate(a + ", " + b, _significantDigits, _pruningLimit);
    }
}
```

My Question:

This runs fine when I start and stop my application. However, when I run unit tests, the tests fail (`System.AccessViolationException`) for the 2nd, 3rd.. and so on runs, but ONLY when I keep the test execution engine alive. This indicates that the unmanaged resources inside `CLICalculator` are disposed (in  the destructor) after each test, but the heap stays alive.

Could the problem be inside the CLI code, where it disposes unmanaged resources wrongfully? Is my overall design flawed? How can I get rid of this `AccessViolationException` during testing?

Comment: What happens if you call two `.Calculate()` calls in a row in the same function? i.e. make `PerformCalculation()` run the calculation twice and only return the second value.

Comment: Sounds to me that you are simply forgetting to reset the _calculator variable back to *null* when the CLICalculator object gets destructed.  That's a bug you should fix.  You can get a "test engine" to create and destroy an AppDomain to clean up managed objects but that's not going to work for unmanaged objects.